# Can I release an iOS app without Simulator (i386) support?

Tags: ios, xcode, size, simulator

I have noticed that, due to a load of libraries, I could reduce my app size a lot by removing the i386 symbols. However I am unsure if this is acceptable from an Apple review point of view as I heard they test in the simulator.

Am I crazy for thinking about removing this support to make my apps smaller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A device build does not include i386 support. If you have libraries that are compiled for i386 exlude them from the final build process (remove them from the target, so they wont be copied to the app bundle)

Comment: An interesting point is that we have static linked library dependencies which are universal (armv6 armv7 i386) and the final build appears to strip out the simulator parts (i.e. no reduction in file size if we replace the universal library with an iOS only version in the dependency).

Answer (score 0):

Your final build shouldn't be including that stuff.  They don't test in the simulator.  Lots of applications won't work in the simulator, such as anything requiring in-app purchases or Game Center integration.

Comment: Apps that use these features can still work in the simulator fine but those features will not work. I find it very useful to make sure that as much as possible can be tested in the simulator for faster development.